# Determinant of specific infinite matrix

Tags: matrices, limits, determinant

What is the limit, as n approaches infinity, of the determinant of an n x n matrix where each cell has the value $\cos(n * row + column)$?

My friend and I believe the answer to be 0, but can't figure out a method of finding the solution without n! steps.

We are interested in how this can be solved as well as the answer.

Comment: Why do you think that the answer's zero?

Comment: Some thoughts: You're evaluating the cosine at integer values (rather than, say, integer multiples of $\pi$) so I'd expect the matrix to consist of entries in $[-1,1]$ with some PDF. Thus you're looking for the determinant of a certain kind of large random matrix...

Comment: @OscarCunningham: We guessed.

Comment: Well, that sounds like a rather feeble basis...

Comment: @Semiclassical Actually, since these are integer values, every entry is in (-1, 1) without any repeat. None of them are going to be a multiple of 2pi, as that's irrational.

Comment: Here are some outputs from Matlab to at least give a sense of the numbers we're working with: $$ n=2:  -0.7651 \\ n=3: 1.9578e-17 \\ n=4: -2.5654e-33 \\ n=5: 0 \\ n=6: 8.5758e-65 \\ n=7: -6.6401e-80 \\ n=8: -2.3124e-96 \\ n=9: 2.0309e-112 \\ n=10: 1.4714e-128 \\ \vdots \\ n=22: 1.2870e-319 \\ n\geq 23: 0$$

Comment: The $e$'s above denote the order of the subsequent exponent, not the mathematical constant $e = 2.718...$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The matrix has determinant equal to $0$ for $n \ge 3$. It is enough to consider the first $3$ rows. After some explicit Gaussian elimination it turns our the following linear combination vanishes

$$r_1 - 2\cos(n) r_2 + r_3 = 0$$

and therefore the first three rows are linearly dependent, so the matrix has determinant $0$. Indeed, we take the $k$-th entry of this row vector

$$r_{1,k} - 2\cos(n) r_{2,k} + r_{3,k} = \cos(n+k) - 2\cos(n)\cos(2n+k) + \cos(3n+k)$$

By the product-to-sum identity we have

$$2\cos(n)\cos(2n+k) = \cos(n+k) + \cos(3n+k)$$

establishing the linear dependence. The same process will yield that the determinant will be zero in the case of a sine matrix of the same form as well (for $n \ge 3$). It's curious to note that if we took $C$ to be the cosine matrix and $S$ to be the sine matrix, together they give a matrix $E = C + iS$ of exponentials. It's quite easy to show that the first two rows of this matrix are linearly dependent and therefore $\det(E) = 0$.

---

Just for completeness here is the Gaussian elimination itself. We start with

$$r_2 \mapsto r_{1,1}r_2 - r_{2,1}r_1 = r_2'$$
$$r_3 \mapsto r_{1,1}r_3 - r_{3,1}r_1 = r_3'$$

Next we do this again for the 3rd row

$$r_3' \mapsto r_{2,2}'r_3' - r_{3,2}'r_2' = r_3''$$

where

$$r_{2,2}' = r_{1,1}r_{2,2} - r_{2,1}r_{1,2} = -\sin(1) \sin(n)$$
$$r_{3,2}' = r_{1,1}r_{3,2} - r_{3,1}r_{1,2} = -\sin(1) \sin(2n)$$

and I've used the product-to-sum identities and then the sum-to-product identities to simplify the expressions. Next we have

$$r_{2,2}'r_3' - r_{3,2}'r_2' = (r_{3,2}'r_{2,1}-r_{2,2}'r_{3,1})r_1 - r_{3,2}'r_{1,1}r_2 + r_{2,2}'r_{1,1}r_3$$

Again, simplifying these expressions we have

$$r_3'' = -\sin(1)\sin(n)\cos(n+1)(r_1 - 2\cos(n) r_2 +  r_3)$$

When performing the actual calculation we can ignore the $-\cos(n+1)\sin(1)\sin(n)$ factor so we really have

$$r_3'' = r_1 - 2\cos(n) r_2 +  r_3$$

Comment: Nice job! I'll give you the bounty in a few hours.